# The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in out-of-range value

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm using Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2012 developing C# program. I want to add records in my database table . The record (object) includes an attribute (TRANSACTION_DATE) which doesn't allow NULL values and it's a DateTime format. In database i'm aiming for this format:

> yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff

so i want to pass the current date and time to it, my code is like this:

```
newEntry.TRASACTION_DATE = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(), 
                            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but it's giving me error:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

I want to know why it's not converting to the format i want?

constraints:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you converting `DateTime.Now` to a string and then back again? Just use `DateTime.Now`... and note that the database value won't *have* a format, intrinsically - the format it happens to use when converting it to a string is irrelevant to what's stored.

Comment: because it's not in the format i want

Comment: I find that these 'datetime out-of-range' exceptions are almost always down to an attempt to store '01-01-0001 00:00:00' in the database, check the SQL being sent to the DB

Comment: if i just want to store the Now time, how could it store '01-01-0001  00:00:00' ?

Comment: Because although you think you might be passing a valid date to a stored procedure (or whatever), you could actually be accidently leaving a field uninitialized. 'out of range' is different to 'could not parse'

Comment: @paul then how can i change this statement to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't think about the database as storing the values in a particular string format at all - any more than it stores numbers as decimal or hex.

Instead, you should just view it as a date/time, e.g.

```
// TODO: Do you really want the local time, rather than UtcNow?
// TODO: Change TRANSACT_DATE to be TransactionDate ideally, to follow
// .NET naming conventions
newEntry.TRANSACT_DATE = DateTime.Now;
```

When you retrieve the value, you should get a `DateTime` at that point too. *Then* if you want to display the value to the user you can apply a particular format. Different users may well want different formats - and may even want to display the same date/time in different time zones.

It's important to differentiate between the intrinsic data you store (in this case a date/time) and the text format that happens to be used to display it any one particular context/application. You should avoid conversions to/from strings at any time when you don't really need one. Ideally, these should only be at the boundaries of your application - e.g. when displaying text to a user, or potentially serializing to JSON or XML. Whenever an API allows you to *not* perform a conversion (e.g. with a database parameter) you should avoid it.

As for your current error - is it possible that it's a different field which you're not populating, and which is therefore using `default(DateTime)`, which would be out of range? That would make a lot of sense - whereas `DateTime.Now` really shouldn't be out of range, unless you've either applied a separate constraint, or your system clock is miles out.

Comment: I used this way in the first place, and it's giving me the same error.

Comment: @lcc: It would help if you'd tell us more about your schema etc. It should be absolutely fine. Do you have any other constraints on your database field? Is it perhaps populated automatically by the database?

Comment: @lcc: See my edited answer for another possibility - I wonder whether it's a different field entirely. Does the error message *say* which value is out of range? How many date/time fields does your database table have?

Comment: i added pictures so you can see these two fields' constaints

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` is irrespective of the format. Presentation format like the one you have is just for displaying purpose. There is no need to convert `DateTime` to string and then parsing it with a custom format. Just simply assign `DateTime` to your field like:

```
newEntry.TRASACTION_DATE = DateTime.Now;
```

`DateTime` in SQL Server has a range of `January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999` Your parsing code is resulting a `DateTime` value less than year `1753` and that is why you are getting the exception.

Comment: i used this one and gave me the same error in the beginning, that's why i want to convert it into the format i want.

Comment: @lcc, what is the data type of `TRANSACTION_DATE` in DB?

Comment: @lcc, try that `newEntry.TRASACTION_DATE = DateTime.Now;` again, it shouldn't throw the exception.

Comment: @lcc - There _is no format_ in the database.  Just use a DateTime variable and be done.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I tried `newEntry.TRASACTION_DATE = DateTime.Now;` and it's giving me same error again.

Comment: @lcc - And what is the value of `newEntry.CREATE_DATE`?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway same: I tried `DateTime.Now;` giving me same error

Answer (score 0):

Can you switch the column type in your database to `datetime2`? This is [Microsoft's recommendation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).  Some .Net `datetime` values don't fit into `datetime`, whereas the `datetime2` type can hold all .Net `datetimes` (and won't introduce subtle bugs by, for example, rounding `2010-05-05 23:59:59.999` to `2010-05-06`).

Note that in contrast to `datetime`, it is not legal to treat `datetime2` as an integer (e.g., by doing stuff like `mydate+1`).

If switching to `datetime2` is not an option, configure your ORM code to explicitly treat this date as `datetime` rather than `datetime2`.  This won't fix your error, but it should cause validation to fail before you send your query rather than afterwards, making it easier to fix.

Regardless of your choice, do not use conversion to/from strings to resolve this problem; that's a hack that causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: It says i would have to drop the table or re-create the table to change the column type to be datetime2. And i couldn't do that.

Comment: how can i configure ORM code to explicitly treat this date as datetime?

Comment: @lcc: During my own testing, dropping the table to change column type is not necessary on condition that you change the column via T-SQL rather than via the SMSS interface (schema-bound stuff will of course interfere), but please verify this yourself on a test DB.  As for changing the ORM code, I don't know what ORM you are using.  In the case of a `SqlParameter`, you would set `DbType` to `System.Data.DbType.DateTime`.